# Using access tokens

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to figure out how an access token in OAuth 2.0 should be used. To be more precise, I am trying to use the Google Plus API from a web application.

I am now able to get a `code` and from it an `access token`. The problem is that this token is only about 3600 seconds valid.

Is there a way to get another token without making the user go again through this process: https://developers.google.com/accounts/images/consent1.png because it seems a bit irritating. I know of the `offline access` and its `refresh token`, but it doesn't feel right to have permanent access to a user's account.

Do you have any ideas on how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm definitely not an authority, but I believe the answer is 'no'. The `offline` token allows you access without subsequent user approval, but only to the scopes to which the user already agreed when authenticating for the first time. Also, the user has the option of revoking your application's access at any time, which when combined with their previous consent means they both a.) know what they're allowing; and  b.) can stop it at any time. Ostensibly, if a user uses your app enough that they constantly have to get a new token, they already trust it to act on their behalf within the scope you set, and the `offline` token is a way for you to take your relationship to the next level :)

I realize this is probably more philosophical than you were looking for, so apologies if it isn't pertinent to your situation.

Comment: Thank you! I have another question then. On Google's documentation it is said that the user sees the aforementioned screen only the first time he logs in and after that that screen is only displayed if the application's access is revoked. I have tested this local, but I always get that consent-screen. What am I missing? Should I access another URL upon log in? Currently it's  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth .

Comment: I have solved this issue. That page was coming up because the `approval_prompt` option was set to `force`. I had forgotten about it. Thank you for your answer, it actually IS what I needed.

Comment: @Dragos Sure thing! Ha, and I was just writing a longer answer that would have done nothing to address that, so thanks for not making me look like an idiot :) Good luck with everything!